# Return copy of dictionary excluding specified keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key, dictionary-comprehension

I want to make a function that returns a copy of a dictionary excluding keys specified in a list.

Considering this dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
    "keyA": 1,
    "keyB": 2,
    "keyC": 3
}
```

A call to `without_keys(my_dict, ['keyB', 'keyC'])` should return:

```
{
    "keyA": 1
}
```

I would like to do this in a one-line with a neat dictionary comprehension but I'm having trouble. My attempt is this:

```
def without_keys(d, keys):
    return {k: d[f] if k not in keys for f in d}
```

which is invalid syntax. How can I do this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You were close, try the snippet below:

```
>>> my_dict = {
...     "keyA": 1,
...     "keyB": 2,
...     "keyC": 3
... }
>>> invalid = {"keyA", "keyB"}
>>> def without_keys(d, keys):
...     return {x: d[x] for x in d if x not in keys}
>>> without_keys(my_dict, invalid)
{'keyC': 3}
```

Basically, the `if k not in keys` will go at the end of the dict comprehension in the above case.

Comment: You declared invalid as a set. Is there a reason for that? Would a list suffice as well?

Comment: Yes, list will suffice as well (you can try it), but generally when order is not important for you, `set` is preferred (even from performance side which is not important in this short example with just a few data).

Comment: Is this faster than getting all keys and then manually skipping not needed keys with a for loop?

Answer (score 47):

In your dictionary comprehension you should be iterating over your dictionary (not `k` , not sure what that is either). Example -

```
return {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k not in keys}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution a little bit more because it makes the (tiny) save of not calling the `d[x]` index operation.

Comment: this is a shallow copy though

Answer (score 13):

This should work for you.

```
def without_keys(d, keys):
    return {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in keys}
```

Answer (score 12):

Even shorter. Apparently python 3 lets you 'subtract' a `list` from a `dict_keys`.

```py
def without_keys(d, keys):
    return {k: d[k] for k in d.keys() - keys}
```

Comment: Note that using `keys()` instead of `items()` is ~33% slower: https://discuss.python.org/t/copy-a-dictionary-except-some-keys/2559/5

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't like list comprehensions, this is my version:

```
def without_keys(d, *keys):
     return dict(filter(lambda key_value: key_value[0] not in keys, d.items()))
```

Usage:

```
>>> d={1:3, 5:7, 9:11, 13:15}
>>> without_keys(d, 1, 5, 9)
{13: 15}
>>> without_keys(d, 13)
{1: 3, 5: 7, 9: 11}
>>> without_keys(d, *[5, 7])
{1: 3, 13: 15, 9: 11}
```

Comment: For those who don't like list comprehensions, you should learn list comprehensions. They are very 'pythonic', and we they eventually click, you will be gald you spent the time to understand them, or else you are fighting the language.

Answer (score 1):

Your oneliner

```
my_dict = {"keyA": 1, "keyB": 2, "keyC": 3}
(lambda keyB, keyC, **kw: kw)(**my_dict)
```

which returns `{'keyA': 1}`.
Not very pythonic and dynamic, but hacky and short.
It uses the dict unpacking (destructuring assignment) of function arguments.

See also
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53851069/11769765.

Answer (score 0):

You could this generalized for nested dictionaries solution

```
def copy_dict(data, strip_values=False, remove_keys=[]):
    if type(data) is dict:
        out = {}
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key not in remove_keys:
                out[key] = copy_dict(value, strip_values=strip_values, remove_keys=remove_keys)
        return out
    else:
        return [] if strip_values else data
```

This recursive solution works for nested dictionaries and removes keys not required from the entire nested structure. It also gives you the ability to return the nest with only keys and no values.