# Create df with dict of dics

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to create a df from the following entries:

```
get_commission = {'info': {'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'makerCommission': '0.001', 'takerCommission': '0.001'}, 'symbol': 'ETH/BTC:BTC', 'maker': 0.001, 'taker': 0.001} 
commission = pd.DataFrame(get_commission)
```

and the output is:

```
                   info       symbol marker  taker
makerCommission   0.001  ETH/BTC:BTC    NaN  0.001
symbol           ETHBTC  ETH/BTC:BTC    NaN  0.001
takerCommission   0.001  ETH/BTC:BTC    NaN  0.001
```

How can I get the df like:

```
symbol marker taker
ETH/BTC:BT 0.001 0.001
```

Thank you

Comment: seems you just need to pass the nested dict `pd.DataFrame([get_commision['info']])`. There is no real pattern here. Pandas dataframe can get data as list of dicts (a.k.a. records), each one has keys as columns names and values as record values.

Comment: or alternatively pass the dict without the `'info'` key. This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433989/return-copy-of-dictionary-excluding-specified-keys

Comment: Please remove the tag of `ccxt` as it is irrelevant to the question asked. Also, can you specify, do you want to create a whole new `df` or get the desired output from the `commission` created above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected result you need to exclude `'info'` key from the input dict:

```
d = {k:v for k, v in get_commission.items() if k != 'info'}
commission = pd.DataFrame([d.values()], columns=d.keys())
```

---

```
        symbol  maker  taker
0  ETH/BTC:BTC  0.001  0.001
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method. If you have multiple dictionary like `info`, include them in `drop` list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([get_commission])
df.drop('info', axis = 1, inplace = True)

symbol  maker  taker
0  ETH/BTC:BTC  0.001  0.001
```