# How to de-structure variables in Python like in React?

Tags: python, local-variables, destructuring

I'm working on creating **APIs** using **Flask**.
For every request, I have to validate either **request.args** or **request.json** and throw error if the **query params** or **request body** is of unexpected form or different **datatype** or **None**.

And then pull out few items from either **request body** or **query params**. There are many such **APIs** where I need to pull out few items from **query params** or **request body** and execute database functions with those values like executing an **SQL** query and passing the data from **request body** or **query params**.

Every time in the **API** view function, I have to do **request.args.get** or **request.json.get** for a number of variables.

I'm just thinking if there is a better way to make the items available in the memory without explicitly pulling each one of them out of the dictionary (Something like de-structuring in **React**).

I've searched and found there is indeed a way to do that which is not preferable.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955476/4626254

I just wanted to know if there is any better approach to do it.

Comment: Python does not support anything like  dictionary destructuring. Just doing it yourself is the best way. Note, that linked answer *is incorrect*.

Comment: Destructure in what context? You can pass a dictionary or tuple as a function argument with * syntax to unpack which is similar to destructuring

Comment: I'm assuming you mean object destructuring in JS, like `{a, b} = {a:1, b:2, c:3}`. But yeah, Python does not support that. In Python, you have to do something like `a = my_dict['a']; b = my_dict['b']`

Comment: yeah. That's what I was referring to. Object destructuring.

Comment: A good option for you might be the "pydantic" project - you can create a class with with the parameters you will use  with minimal fuzz, and pass your json to it to get to an validated Python object that is easy to use. https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/ - or just write a base class, and instance classes with your desired fields yourself - it is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is `operator.itemgetter`, which lets you retrieve multiple items at once. (Semantically, it's still extracting each value from the `dict`; syntactically, it's one operation, though.)

```
from operator import itemgetter

keys = ['a', 'b']
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

get_a_and_b = itemgetter(*keys)  # equivalent to lambda d: (d['a'], d['b'])

values = get_a_and_b(d)  # KeyError if either a or b is missing, otherwise returns (1, 2)

d2 = dict(zip(keys, values))  # Build new "subdict" if desired.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make you code cleaner instead of getting each value one by one from `dict`, don't want to type the same key twice to have them available as variables- then create some auxiliary function which unpack values that you need as function arguments or keyword arguments (depending if they have to be required or can have default values) and keep rest as `**kwargs`. Eg.

```
params = {c: i for i, c in enumerate('abcd')}

def get_abcx_sum_and_rest(a, b, c=1, x=2, **kwargs):
    return sum((a,b,c,x)), kwargs

abcx_sum, rest_dct = get_abcx_sum_and_rest(**params)
```

Js es6 syntax is nice, but sadly not available in python. I think that if you need to do something with certain keys of your dict, then it's probably the case when you should enclose and name those actions in a separate function.