# How can i do this javascript code on Python 3?

Tags: javascript, python

I have this line on JavaScript, but i want to know what's the equivalent of that in Python.

```js
const { entities, classification } = obj
```

The complete function is:

```js
function extractActionEntities (lang, expressionsFilePath, obj) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        log.title('NER')
        log.info('Searching for entities...')

        // Need to instanciate on the fly to flush entities
        this.nerManager = new NerManager()

        const { entities, classification } = obj
        // Remove end-punctuation and add an end-whitespace
        const query = `${string.removeEndPunctuation(obj.query)} `
        const expressionsObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(expressionsFilePath, 'utf8'))
        const { module, action } = classification
        const promises = []
    });
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is **not** a code-writing service, you must at least make an honest attempt to solve your problem before opening a question about it.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand or I didn't make myself understood.  I don't want them to write code for me, I just want to know how I do that line in Python.

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay attention to the *line* part. If you care to edit anything in your question, I can remove the *downvote* casted.

Comment: Sorry man, i can't remove that line, i didn't want to add that line, but the Stack Overflow's policies forces me. Nevermind, i got the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't use constants, so you have to port only the destructuring, which Python also doesn't have (at least not exactly like ES6).

You can, however, do this:

```py
entities, classification = [obj[k] for k in ("entities", "classification")]
```

Or, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52083390/5160230), use the `itemgetter`.

```py
from operator import itemgetter
entities, classification = itemgetter("entities", "classification")(obj)
```