# Python Deep Destruction Like JavaScript and assingment to new Object

Tags: javascript, python, object, destruction

```js
let newJson = {};

({
    "foo": {
        "name": newJson.FirstName,
        "height": newJson.RealHeight
    }
} =

{
    "foo": {
        "name": "Felipe",
        "height": "55"
    }
});
console.log({newJson})
```

As we Know the above code will return in JS the follow output:

```js
{newJson :{FirstName: "Felipe", RealHeight: "55"}}
```

I Would like to kwnow if there is a Lib or a way to do it in PYTHON

Comment: Look at the `json` standard library. Find the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: You mean "desctructured", not "desctructive".

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "desctructured assignment in Python" yields results.

You can use the native "tuple unpacking" as defined in [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) :

```py
json_data = {
    "foo": {
        "name": "Felipe",
        "height": "55"
    }
}

first_name, real_height = json_data["foo"]["name"], json_data["foo"]["height"]

print(first_name, real_height)
# Felipe 55
```

Or you can use something a bit closer which is based on the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) (inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52083390/11384184)) :

```py
from operator import itemgetter

json_data = {
    "foo": {
        "name": "Felipe",
        "height": "55"
    }
}

first_name, real_height = itemgetter("name", "height")(json_data["foo"])

print(first_name, real_height)
# Felipe 55
```

Comment: What I need is something that could be deep, tuple unpacking i know but not enouth

Comment: @FelipeAugustoGonalvesBasili Python does **not** permit it with the current parser.