# js style dictionary deconstruction in python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

here is javascript code

```
var {a,b,c}=my_dict
```

The code takes the some parameters from a dictionary (called object in js) and defines them as local variables so they can be easily accessed later in the function. I like the syntax because it only uses a variable name once.

My question is: is there a similar feature in python?

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent that is as convenient as javascript here. There are some [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955412/destructuring-bind-dictionary-contents) with solutions that get you about half way there.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't called objects in JS, btw. The closest equivalent to a Python  `dict` object is a JS `Map` object